# Problems creating symbolic links on Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, symbolic-link

I am experiencing strange behavior on my Mac. When I create a symbolic link with command `ln -s` nothing happens and when I do listing a directory no symbol link appears. So I tried creating the symbolic link again but I got the error "File exists".

Do you know where the problem is?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you havent switched files in between. See this manual. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115646/how-can-i-create-a-symbolic-link-in-terminal

Comment: even I swithed the files it doesnt wokrs. but thanks for the manual.

Comment: I think you made your links inside the folder paper-works. look at it

Comment: Your post needs to be expanded. A good [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) includes specific instructions ([not just links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) to them) and an explanation as to how or why the answer addresses the OPs question.  Please edit your post to adequately address both of these elements.